# Android and a SQL Server database

Tags: android, sql-server, database

I have a big SQL Server database I want to connect to and my question is, what is the best way going forward? And some link or bits of code would be appreciated.

My knowledge of databases is limited.

The problem is that a web service exists but it's currently using SOAP which I simply can not get to work with Android (yes, I've tried k2SOAP and others alike). I know Android supports restservice but maybe there is a simpler way.

- Maybe connect to SQL Server through PHP?
- Copy the database to MySQL and use PHP?
- I'm suggesting PHP because I've actually worked with PHP so I know it. It might be more trouble to re-code the web-service?

I would be greatly appreciate any help. I'm doing this for a company so the less I need to "mess" with their database the better.

[UPDATE]
I'm asking what is the most cost efficient, cheapest and fastest way of doing this?

I know this was a vague question but this is in simple what I want to do.

I've accepted the question below as the answer, since it seems to be the most cost-efficent way of doing this.

Comment: I've changed the question and made it more clear what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ready to connect to the MSSQL database using PHP, why not simply create a RESTful based webservice. 
If you create a PHP file to connect to the database, then also you'll be needing a mechanism to connect to the PHP file from Android. Same would be the case with RESTful service.

I would suggest to go with a JSON based RESTful service.

Comment: But it looks so easy using a MySQL database: http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php/ I've never worked with MSSQL databases so I don't know how easy it is to connect to MSSQL databases with PHP. And even less creating a restful service.

Do you have any links or tips on how to create one?

Comment: Yes, it very easy to connect MySql with PHP. I mentioned MSSQL because you had mentioned it in your question (In your third para). Let me know in case you have more questions or need any kind of help.